# OR-CCSEH-21 - React Google Pay Integration

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, google-pay

When integrated with React and continued the payment

The following is the configurations, that I have been trying on, also tried removing stripe as payment gateway, but still doesnt work

**CODE:**

```
import React from "react";
import GooglePayButton from "@google-pay/button-react";
const Gpay = () => {
  console.log("here");
  return (
    <GooglePayButton
      environment="TEST"
      paymentRequest={{
        apiVersion: 2,
        apiVersionMinor: 0,
        allowedPaymentMethods: [
          {
            type: "CARD",
            parameters: {
              allowedAuthMethods: ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"],
              allowedCardNetworks: ["MASTERCARD", "VISA"],
            },
            tokenizationSpecification: {
              type: "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
              parameters: {
                gateway: "stripe",
                "stripe:version": "v3",
                "stripe:publishableKey":
               "<pub_key_added>",
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        merchantInfo: {
          merchantId: "12345678901234567890",
          merchantName: "Demo Merchant",
        },
        transactionInfo: {
          totalPriceStatus: "FINAL",
          totalPriceLabel: "Total",
          totalPrice: "100.00",
          currencyCode: "USD",
          countryCode: "US",
        },
      }}
      onLoadPaymentData={(paymentRequest) => {
        console.log("load payment data", paymentRequest);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Gpay;
```

**ERROR:**
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veH2p.png)

I am trying to integrate google pay using @google-pay/button-react

Comment: Please don’t post errors as screenshots. What is the link to the “learn more” page? What does it say?

Comment: Could you join the testing group with your Google Account and try again with a test card? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data

Comment: if you get the solution can you please share, I'm getting the same error